# How to limit the input based on the value of another input using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Html:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-2">
     Paid Balance</strong>: <input type="text" name="paidbalance" id="paidbalance" class="form-control"  />
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-md-2" >
     Balance</strong>: <input type="text" name="balance" id="balance" class="form-control"  value="200" readonly/>
        </div>
```

Hello, Can anyone help me with this problem. How to limit the input based on the value of another input using javascript .
For Example the Value of Balance Input is 200 so that the possible input in PaidBalance is within 0-200 only.

Sorry, I'm just a student. Thanks :):)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is with pure javascript without jquery. Also, note that the accepted answer doesn't work if user paste some value with mouse right-click: paste option.

```js
function f1()
{
  var max = Number(document.getElementById("balance").value);
  var paid = document.getElementById("paidbalance");
  var v = Number(paid.value);
  //if(isNaN(v)) {...} //input is not a number
  if(v>max) {
    paid.focus(); //to keep focus on input
    paid.value=max; //you may comment out this line to don't override value
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-2">
     Paid Balance</strong>: <input type="text" name="paidbalance" id="paidbalance" class="form-control"  oninput="f1()" />
</div>
        
<div class="col-md-2" >
     Balance</strong>: <input type="text" name="balance" id="balance" class="form-control"  value="200"  />
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```js
$("#paidbalance").keyup(()=>{
  const balance = parseFloat($("#balance").val())
  const paidBalance = parseFloat($("#paidbalance").val())
  
  if( paidBalance > balance)
    $("#paidbalance").val(balance)
  else if(paidBalance < 0)
    $("#paidbalance").val(0)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Paid Balance
</strong>: <input type="text" name="paidbalance" id="paidbalance" class="form-control"  />
        
Balance
</strong>: <input type="text" name="balance" id="balance" class="form-control"  value="200"   readonly/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might wanna change the type to `number` in this case and add `max` property in `input`. If the value of balance Input is different every time. You might considering assign it to a variable and pass it to the `max` property

```
 Paid Balance</strong>: 
<input type="number" name="paidbalance" id="paidbalance" max="200" class="form-control"  />
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the input to `type="number"` and add jQuery like this:

```
var balance = $('#balance')
var paidBalance = $('#paidbalance')

paidBalance[0].setAttribute('max', balance.val())
```

Example:
https://jsfiddle.net/Daniel_Knights/t4hb0z7p/8/